# Connecting to Alexa with FAUXMOESP library not detecting the device

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am using NodeMCU (ESP8266 12E) module from some days. I am trying to connect to Alexa for voice controlling. I have Amazon Alexa Echo 2 from which I am trying to discover my nodemcu as a smart home device.

Here is my sketch I am trying to use to detect.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <fauxmoESP.h>

fauxmoESP fauxmo;

const char* ssid = "myssid";
const char* password = "mypassword";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  wifisetup();

  fauxmo.enable(true);

  fauxmo.addDevice("light one");
  fauxmo.addDevice("light two");

// this is not able to detect .onSetState function I am not sure about the reason. 

//  fauxmo.onSetState([](unsigned char device_id, const char * device_name, bool state, unsigned char value) {
//        Serial.printf("[MAIN] Device #%d (%s) state: %s value: %d\n", device_id, device_name, state ? "ON" : "OFF", value);
//    });
}

void loop() {
    fauxmo.handle();

}


void wifisetup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 243); // this 3 lines for a fix IP-address
  IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
  IPAddress dns(192, 168, 1, 1);
  WiFi.config(ip, dns, gateway, subnet);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connection Failed! Rebooting...");
    delay(10000);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Your ESP is connected!");
    Serial.println("Your IP address is: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    delay(100);
  }

}
```

I am using https://bitbucket.org/xoseperez/fauxmoesp library to do the setup. Alexa is not able to detect my device. Not sure whats the issue with this, but in the Serial Monitor I can see the logs which is showing that I am getting ping from Alexa to my ESP8266.

Taking an output pin is compulsory? I have tried that too although but no output found.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using fauxmoESP library version 3.0 and above your device will not be detected by alexa, i dont know why this is.
You may degrade fauxmoESp version to 2.4.0 so that your issue ie. .onSetState will be resolved.

Are you able to connect wifi?

Comment: Yes it worked before itself. And yes i was able to connect through Wifi.

Comment: 2.4.0 is not available anymore.. any idea which one works now?